# checking user file if user has admin access

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I am writing a very program that checks if a user is logged in with the correct username and password and also if a user has admin access . the password file is a simple text file with the columns seperated by tabs. the login part works, but I can't get the code to check if a user has admin access to work. if a user is an admin then they access to a separate menu than a normal user.

This is the definition code to check the file for the user type:

```
def admin_user():
  with open("password.txt", "r") as f:
    is_admin = False
    for line in f:
      loginInfo = line.split("\t")
      if loginInfo[2] == "admin":
        is_admin = True
        
      
    return is_admin
```

The menu should be something like this:

```
if admin_user():
    print("do something ")
```

In the program both admin users and regular users see the same menu even if in the username file they only have regular access.

Comment: Are you sure that `loginInfo[2]` contains the `admin` string? Split arrays start at 0. Can you also post some line examples of your `password.txt` file?

Comment: I ran the following code to check file           with open("password.txt", "r") as f:
    
    for line in f:
        loginInfo = line.split("\t")
        user_type = loginInfo[2]
        print(user_type) it prints the user type correctly

Comment: donieD Sn3akyC admin
MikeOD pass123 regular  
john password123 regular  this is the contents of the file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, I think your `admin_user()` is missing a parameter.

As is, you're only checking if the `admin` string is present once or more in your `password.txt` file but you don't check to which user it is associated to so the result is the same for all users.

What about something like:

```py
def admin_user(username: str):
  with open("password.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      loginInfo = line.split("\t")
      if loginInfo[0] == username and loginInfo[2] == "admin":
        return True
            
    return False
```

And you would have to call it with a username:

```py
if admin_user("donieD"): # you probably want to use a variable here instead of a static string
    print("do something")
```

This call should succeeds for `donieD` given your `password.txt` example.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer when I run the following I get normal access even though it should be admin  def admin_user(username):
  
  with open("password.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      loginInfo = line.split("\t")
      if loginInfo[0] == username and loginInfo[2] == "admin":
        return True
            
    return False


print("Please enter your username to check for admin access")
name = input()
if admin_user(name):
    ("Print You have admin access")

else:
    print("normal access")

Comment: I think you are close but your `password.txt` is not correctly formatted. I would try to debug by printing each line + `loginInfo[0]` + `logInfo[2]`. You can also clean each entry/line with `strip()`. Maybe also check that each line contains entries separated by tabulations and not spaces?